# Runtime error while using Mailchimp in asp.net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailchimp

I am trying to access mailchimp using it's api.I have installed mail chimp using
 Install-Package MailChimp.NET in package console. I have used the code

```
MailChimpManager mc = new MailChimpManager("44c406b82d7deb236e88b214363368fa-us3");
ListResult lists = mc.GetLists();
```

While running the application the below error occurs

> "Could not load type 'MailChimp.MailChimpManager' from assembly
>   'Mailchimp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

Comment: I think u have forget to referance dll

Answer (score 3):

I got this error myself and found that by having an application (`MailChimp.exe`) of the same name as the DLL (`MailChimp.dll`) caused a failure in the load process.

Try renaming your exe's assembly name (in project properties) to something other than `MailChimp.exe`.

Comment: Thanks, It works for me. I have console app with same as that of MailChimp. I simply change my application name, its start working.